# Elm 'Hello World' program not running when using elm-reactor

Tags: elm, elm-reactor

I just started using Elm. When I ran my hello world example(link to screenshot of code used given below) using *elm-reactor*, there is blank page on browser. There is also an error message on console describing it as a reference error (link to the screenshot given below). But, when using *elm-make* to create a html file from the code, it runs successfully.

[Link to tutorial site referred to write the hello world example.](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/01-foundations/01-hello.html)

Please help me in finding the solution to the problem. If you need further information, just leave a comment.

Elm code used:

```
module Hello exposing (..)

import Html exposing ( text, Html )

main : Html a
main = text "Hello"
```

Error message on browser console:

```
ReferenceError: runElmProgram is not defined.
```

Browser output is blank screen.

Comment: Please edit the question to include text snippets of the code and console output rather than relying on externally hosted screen shots, which may disappear over time.

Comment: Okay @MikeGodin, will do that in a minute

Comment: What happens if you change to `module Hello ...` and `Hello.elm`? (capital H)

Comment: The same code fails to run on elm online editor as well. If the first line `module hello..` line is removed, it runs smoothly.

Comment: Some GitHub issues suggest that you could be having these problems because of using outdated versions. Please try to install the latest elm-platform!

Comment: @AlexLew Your changes didn't help. Got an additional error at console though:                                                                                                        `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/_compile/Hello.elm”. `

Comment: @kaskelotti I don't know how you are doing it, but i'm still not able to do it. Error message after the changes suggested by you remains same as that for changes suggested by AlexLew.

Comment: @kaskelotti I don't think the problem is due to the outdated version. Although, at first I was running 0.17, but even after updating it to 0.18 same problem persists. HTML file produced by elm-make is running successfully but elm-reactor way is not yielding any result.

Comment: @Transhap I copied the code from your question and ran it with elm-reactor. With lowercase module name it fails, but not with the same error message as you have. By fixing that it runs nicely. Elm version is 0.18.

Comment: I'd recommend you to start a fresh project, make sure the `elm-package.json` has elm version set to 0.18 and the command line tool in use is version 0.18. To see the version number type command `elm-reactor --help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Maybe, it was due to the way I installed Elm (build from source). Solved it by installing elm again from scratch using *npm*.

Answer (score 0):

In Elm module names and file names should start from a capital letter. Just rename your module to Hello and your file to Hello.elm.

Comment: I guess at this point it will be way easier to help you if you share your code in github repo.

Comment: Thank you @gyzerok. I don't think there is any need of it. I have sorted it out. It was probably due to the way I build Elm.